# Ubuntu GNOME display fails to start on boot

Tags: 16.04, gnome, encryption, gdm, cryptsetup

I have made a fresh Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1 install through USB and there were no problems during the first boot. Booting my OS a second time throws me immediately to *tty1*. Here is what I have tried:

- Booting from my USB again then trying to boot from Hard drive initializes the display successfully. However, as with the original symptom, once I shutdown my computer and re-start it again throws me to *tty1*
- in *tty1*, I have tried issuing `service gdm stop` & `service gdm start` with sudo privileges. Nothing worked.
- in *tty1*, issuing `sudo startx` starts my display manager with **root** as the current user. Using a terminal window, restarting the *gdm* service as above successfully initiate the GDM with me as the current user.
- in *tty1,* typing `startx` without root privileges fails

Are there any défaux with init scripts ? I have updated my packages.

**EDIT 1:** Issuing `sudo service gdm restart` reactivates the graphical tty7 and solves the problem. However, I have to enter it every time at boot.
My guess is that there are some components related to GDM initialization that load after GDM or something similar.

**EDIT 2:** After being dropped to tty1, my "num-lock" flickers very rapidly for about 20 seconds. If I typed my user name and password during this period, I am logged in into the Graphical interface as normal. If not, then I have to manually restart GDM.
What is worth noting though, is that every time I change "Automatic Login" to *ON*, I find it *OFF* after the next boot.

*Note:* I have my / encrypted. My "/boot" resides on a separate partition

Answer (score 0):

My most accurate guess is that this happens because I have encrypted my home directory (in addition to the disk encryption) during installation:

[image: Entering your credentials]