# Encrypted partition mounts but encrypted home doesn't

Tags: encryption

I am trying to mount my encrypted partition (which includes my home folder) from a USB with Ubuntu installed. Nautilus prompts me to write my passphrase after clicking on my partition name. After successful input, however, my home folder isn't accessible at all.

I do not think this is a permission's problem. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when the home folder is encrypted, it must be with the same password than the user password.
In this case, the home folder will be automatically unlocked when you'll enter your Account.

Comment: In normal boots from my Hard disk, I get stuck into a tty1 after I type the passphrase and I have to enter my username/password again. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/847939/ubuntu-gnome-display-fails-to-start-on-boot